# on trying to create databricks_user using terraform getting an error

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, databricks, terraform-provider-databricks

On trying to create databricks_user using terraform getting an error

```
module.user.databricks_user.users["my.email@mycompany.com"]: Creating...
╷
│ Error: cannot create user: HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL
│ 
│   with module.user.databricks_user.users["my.email@mycompany.com"],
│   on ../../modules/user/users.tf line 1, in resource "databricks_user" "users":
│    1: resource "databricks_user" "users" {
│
```

And here is my actual code

```
resource "databricks_user" "users" {
  user_name = "my.email@mycompany.com"
}
```

Why am I getting `HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL` ? How do I fix it? I am deploying resources on databricks on AWS

Comment: See https://github.com/databricks/terraform-provider-databricks/issues/2183

Comment: I would try it without the `force = true` parameter.

Comment: are you trying to create it on the account level, or on workspace level? What is your default provider configuraiton?